# Geocortex query; zoom to results

Tags: query, zoom, geocortex

Is there a setting in Geocortex so that you can zoom to query results by clicking on them?

I must be missing something.  The results look good but I see no way to click and get to the visible shapefile results.

Comment: Depending on how you search and how the results are displayed, it is indeed possible to zoom to a result when clicked.

You may want to post this question to the Geocortex support forums to get a better response.

Answer (score 1):

If running a workflow, you can GetFeatureSetExtent and then RunExternalCommand with Command Name "ZoomToScale" or "ZoomToExtent".

Or depending on how your Context Menus are set from your Geocortex Essentials Manager, you can addd 'Zoom to Feature' into the Map Tips or Results List. It's in the Feature Actions context menu by default.